# The end of stream is not being detected by reader.EndOfStream

Tags: c#, .net-core, streamreader

I am reading strings from command line. But end of stream can not be detected by my program. How do I reconstruct this or is there a way to explicitly set EndOfStream to true?

```
List<String> str = new List<String>();

        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(Console.OpenStandardInput()))

            while (!reader.EndOfStream)
            {
                string line = reader.ReadLine();

                if (line != string.Empty)
                {
                    str.Add(line);
                }
            }
```

Comment: Why do you expect the Console stream to have ended? The stream should stay open till the program is closed.

Comment: `ReadLine()` will normally return `null` if the end of the stream is reached anyways, so you don't even need to check `EndOfStream`. Howevever, in your case it's not going to work because, by design, the console never reaches its end. You'll have to find another method of determining when data is done being entered.

Answer (score 1):

That cannot work out by design. The stdin/stdout console streams are opened  as long as the program is active. The `EndOfStream` is executed just before you close the application in this case.

A good solution for your issue is.

```
using System;

public class Example
{
   public static void Main()
   {
      string line;
      do { 
         line = Console.ReadLine();
         if (line != null) 
            Console.WriteLine("Now I have detected the end of stream.... " + line);
      } while (line != null);   
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is fine.
When reading from the console, EOF is indicated by entering:
^z then ENTER.

This is a standard as old as DOS. Unix has a similar standard, but it is ^d.

Bill Gates either didn't know Unix or chose to be different but not better. This is why it is ^z not ^d

Likewise, DOS and Windows treat "/" as a command line option delimiter, even though "/" and "" are handled by windows internals as path delimiters.